# Make the Clock component truly reusable and encapsulated? in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

```js
function Clock(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
      <h2>It is {props.date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

function tick() {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Clock date={new Date()} />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
}

setInterval(tick, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Question:
people, please explain the below code, here how are we moving to the second function like{without kind of any callback function}?

Comment: Here it is:  <Clock date={new Date()} />. The key word is "Clock". Literally: setInterval repeat this:  ReactDOM.render the first function Clock in the "root" element. That's it.

Comment: yup, got it, Thanks @Max Kurtz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by moving your `setInterval` up in your component and use it to update its state to make it re-render.

Also, `reactDOM.render` should only ever be called once.

Working example :

```js
class Clock extends React.Component{

    state = { date: new Date() }

    componentDidMount(){
        setInterval(() => { this.setState({ date: new Date() })}, 1000);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
                <h2>It is {this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Clock />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```